# SSL Connection error in Ruby 1.9.3-p392+

Tags: ruby, ssl, ruby-1.9.3, rest-client, ruby-2.0

In Ruby 1.9.3-p385 or earlier, I can successfully run the following piece of code:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://secure.example.com')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'

http.start do |h|
  h.request Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
end
```

In Ruby 1.9.3-p392 or above, I receive the following error:

```
/Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)
    from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
    from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    from /Users/jason/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:557:in `start'
```

- I have installed both versions of Ruby under the latest version of rbenv
- I am running OpenSSL 1.0.1e
- I am running OSX 10.8.3 (latest version)

Is there some major difference in how SSL is handled between Ruby 1.9.3p-385 and 1.9.3-p392?

Essentially, the end goal is to connect to some API endpoint using SSL (https://secure.example.com), without passing details of any SSL certificates from the client side. Ideally I will be able to achieve this using the rest-client Gem (this throws the same error as the code above).

Comment: Passing 'VERIFY_NONE' as the OpenSSL verify_mode does not seem to make a difference - I still receive this error

Comment: How you resolved this issue?

Comment: @PramodShinde  I believe the issue was down to the installation of OpenSSL on my machine. I tried the same code on a fresh EC2 instance, and managed to run this successfully. Not 100% sure what the issue was though

Answer (score 0):

try to set http.ssl_version = :SSLv3, it might be that your API is using a different SSL version

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe the issue was down to the installation of OpenSSL on my machine. I tried the same code on a fresh EC2 instance, and managed to run this successfully. Still investigating!